# What's the algorithm behind buffered / streamed online video?

Tags: algorithm, youtube, video-streaming, vimeo

Is it simply a question of adjusting the amount of prebuffered content depending on network speed?  Do you adjust for this once at the beginning, every second...?

Or is it more complicated - sampling a history of recordings of your network speed and taking the mean / median and adjusting on that??

Answer (score 2):

Your second paragraph sums it up pretty well.

The client looks at how fast the previous chunk of audio/video *(usually just a second or two's worth)* downloaded, then requests a bitrate of video it thinks it can handle downloading fast enough.  It always buffers (downloads) at least several seconds into the future, to give itself leeway in case the next chunk of audio/video downloads slower than expected.

Note that every combination of bitrate and resolution needs to be encoded separately.   They're usually pre-encoded and stored on the server.  So how many bitrates there are to choose from, and what they are, completely depends on whoever encoded and/or is hosting the content.

Comment: I wish they were a little more conservative or intelligent about it.  Buffering pauses are one of the worst things about having personal film collections in the cloud. How do you know that's how they do it, by the way? WOuld really appreciate a source :).  Thanks.

Comment: prior knowledge?  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media#Codec.2C_bitstream.2C_transport.2C_control) for a list of protocols, if you're really interested in the intrinsics.

Comment: Is this speculative?? Some links/references to support this?